# git default parameter on push

Tags: git, gitlab

I need to do `git push origin -o ci.skip` so I do not trigger a massive gitlab pipeline. (when they become large I move them to scheduled).

Is there a way to set up projects ~/.git/config so this parameter is on per default.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to take a look at aliases:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

That way you could specify some other command, e.g. `pushs`:
`git config --local alias.pushs 'push origin -o ci.skip'`

Then you could just type `git pushs`

Comment: I will try aliases, Now I need to find a way for my editor to pick it up.